# What does "operator MyType () {}" mean in C++

Tags: c++

I see a function member in a c++ class:

```
class bar{
//..
}

class foo{
public:
    foo(){};
    //...
    operator bar(){
       return bar();
    }
}
```

it's not an operator overloading, can anyone explain it to me ?

Comment: `operator bar()` is a conversion operator to convert instances of `foo` to `bar`. [user-defined conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) `return bar();` returns a default constructed instance of `bar()`. (This is a bit stupid conversion but correct concerning C++.) ;-)

Comment: When providing such a conversion operator, carefully consider whether it should have the [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) specifier or not.  (In my experience, 9 times out of 10 it ought to have `explicit`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a [user-defined conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) which constructs a `bar` object from the `foo` object. The purpose is to enable type casting from `foo` to `bar`.